# How do I get element name in xslt/xquery

Tags: xml, xslt, xquery

For example I have this XML

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<employee>
   <JOHN>
      <branch>0</branch>
   </JOHN>
   <ANDY>
      <branch>0996</branch>
   </ANDY>
   <ADAM>
      <branch>0996</branch>
   </ADAM>
</employee>
```

How can I get value of each element using XQuery?
I want to get get

```
JOHN
ANDY
ADAM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the XPath expression `/employee/*/name()` you will (with XSLT 2.0 or later or with XQuery 1.0 or later) get a sequence of strings with the element names. In XSLT 1.0 you would need to process `/employee/*` using `for-each` or `apply-templates` and then output the `name()` for each element processed separately.

So a complete XSLT 2.0 stylesheet is

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="/employee/*/name()"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Online sample at http://xsltransform.net/ej9EGc7.

Comment: Perhaps worth mentioning that it might be more appropriate to use `local-name()` here instead of `name()`. `name()` returns the lexical QName, whereas local-name() returns just the name excluding any prefix or namespace information (that might be present in other examples).